# Is there a way to save in a file all information from "free" command and "vmstat" command including time?

Tags: memory, debian

I need it every 2 minutes:[image: free command]

My server is Debian (text mode only)

Comment: Is it possible save in XML format instead of txt file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## How do I save the output of `free`/`vmstat` every two minutes?

Via **`cron`, `date` and *output redirection***.

If you need the output of `free` every so often (in this case, two minutes), this is an ideal job for [`cron`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab):

> The software utility **Cron** is a time-based job scheduler in Unix-like computer operating systems. People who set up and maintain software environments use cron to schedule jobs (commands or shell scripts) to run periodically at fixed times, dates, or intervals.

Quoted from the first paragraph of the [Wikipedia article on `cron`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

### `free`, `vmstat` and a `date`

First, the output you want. You don't say how you want it formatted; so if all you want is a date/time and the unaltered output, `echo`* will work fine:

```
$ echo -e "`date`\n\n`free`\n\n`vmstat`"
Tue 28 Mar 00:32:07 BST 2017

             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:      16392592   16204636     187956     280584    9257448    1249596
-/+ buffers/cache:    5697592   10695000
Swap:       964604          0     964604

procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 1  0      0 187956 9257448 1249596    0    0   201    24  111   84  5  1 94  0  0
```

If that is indeed what you want. Note that `free` can be formatted in 'human-readable' numbers, by passing `-h`:

```
 $ free -h
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           15G        15G       227M       274M       8.8G       1.2G
-/+ buffers/cache:       5.5G        10G
Swap:         941M         0B       941M
```

<sup><sup>*</sup> some people might tell you to use [`printf`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/printf) instead, eg `printf "%s\n\n%s\n\n\%s\n\n" "$(date)" "$(vmstat)" "$(free)"`). Note that we had to supply an `-e` switch to `echo` above to enable backslash escapes; though this is not needed in the `crontab` later.</sup>

### Every so often to a file - via `cron` and redirection

As above, `cron` will execute a command according to a specified interval.

In your case, every two minutes, you might want something like:

```
$ crontab -l

# m     h       dom     mon     dow     command
  */2   *       *       *       *       echo -e "`date`\n\n`free`\n\n`vmstat`\n" >> /home/root/free_vmstat_output.txt
```

Note that `crontab -l` lists the contents of the `crontab`; `crontab -e` opens it in the default editor.

Here `*/2` in the `m` column means '*every two minutes*', the `*` in the other columns means *'every hour/day of month/month/day of week'*.

The `>>` after the command is an [output redirector](https://linux.die.net/Intro-Linux/sect_05_01.html#sect_05_01_02), this case it means (more or less) *'append this output to the following file'*.

### TL;DR

If you want to save the output of `date`, `free` and `vmstat` toa file every two minutes add the following line to your crontab (via `crontab -e`):

```
  */2   *       *       *       *       echo "`date`\n\n`free`\n\n`vmstat`\n" >> /home/root/free_vmstat_output.txt
```

---

#### Further Reading

*I am not affiliated with any of the following, but they may be of some help*.

- ['Intro to `cron`'](http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html) from unixgeeks.
- [input/output redirection](https://linux.die.net/Intro-Linux/sect_05_01.html#sect_05_01_02) from 'Intro to Linux' (or a [different one](http://sc.tamu.edu/help/general/unix/redirection.html) from TAMU.edu)
- [`printf` info](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/printf)

Comment: Is it possible save in XML format instead of txt file?

Comment: Yes of course, but that might be better dealt with in a separate question where you can elaborate a bit more on your requirements :)

Comment: :https://superuser.com/questions/1193701/how-to-save-in-xml-json-format-all-information-from-free-command-and-vmstat